# Mermin-Wagner theorem for curved spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, symmetry-breaking, spacetime-dimensions

i'm searching for the [Mermin-Wagner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%E2%80%93Wagner_theorem) formulation for negative curvature surfaces. Something like that exist?